# Why can't I use weapons during the quest 'Dangerous Minds' in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

Whenever I start the quest 'Dangerous Minds', my weapon automatically lowers itself and is unusable. The item is still equipped as it shows in my Pitboy but it will not raise no matter what button i press (I play on Xbox One). I have tried going back to before the mission starts and equipping different weapons but nothing seems to work. How do i raise my gun again?

Comment: @Timelord64: why you rmeoved the xbox-one tag? its pretty much what theese tags are for if platform related behaving is expected. I was going to even remove the part out of the post to get in as tag but now I'm courious why you did the opposite?

Comment: @Zaibis, what makes you think the xbox one tag is even appropriate? This is not an issue you are having with the actual console, itself. It is a problem with the game. Console tags are to be used if you are asking about either the console, itself, or a feature exclusive to that console. Your question applies to all versions, and so it should not used. Im not sure why you would think it is xbox specific, though. You have even accepted an answer that states 'thats how it is suppose to be'

Comment: @Timelord64 This question was asked by someone else...

Comment: @Timelord64: I never even played the game. jsut wondering. Since "or a feature exclusive to that console." OP sounds to me like he is assuming, he experiences an bug, what might be platform depending! so xboxone specific behaving. and even after clearifying it is not a bug, the OP's initial intention was xbox one related. I learned on other SE pages this belongs to a tag and not written info. So independend about the tag is appropiate or not... In anyway the information about plattform doesn't belong into text. Or is that different on gaming SE page?

Comment: @Zaibis I think that Timelord was correct in removing the tag *after* the answer accepted indicated that it was not a platform-specific issue. For future use, it doesn't make sense to keep a question tag that no longer accurately indicates a possible aspect of the problem. This is just my opinion.

Comment: @nukeforum: I'm fine with that. But shouldn't be the platform information then be removed from the text, too?.... or even in ANY case?

Comment: @Zaibis Well, I would agree, but in this case, the author is clarifying the statement "...button i press."[sic] by saying that s/he is playing on some kind of console. I don't think it's imperative to remove all mention, but I think the tag does some work in driving people away from an answer if it doesn't match their platform.

Comment: @Zaibis If you feel like this issue needs attention, you should post in the meta about it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The quest is making you relive Kellogg's memories. You can not use your weapons during this sequence.

http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dangerous_Minds